# Perl: How to check if any integers in a list of integers are in an array

Tags: arrays, perl

Similar to my earlier question, but this time I would like to know if any integers in a list of integers are in an array.

For example, if I have:

```
@int_array = (7,101,80,22,42);
```

How can I check if the integer value 80 or 77 or 99 is in the array? Is there a better way than just doing a separate smartmatch for each integer in the list? I'm using Perl 5.10.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use 5.012;

my @array = (7,101,80,22,42);
my @items = (77,81,99);
my $it = join '|', @items;
my $re = qr/^(?:$it)\z/; 
say $re ~~ @array ? 'OK' : 'Not OK';
```

Answer (score 4):

I think the best answer here is:

```
perldoc -q "How can I tell whether a certain element is contained in a list or array?"
```

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-can-I-tell-whether-a-certain-element-is-contained-in-a-list-or-array%3f

Answer (score 1):

you can turn the array into a hash, so instead of having to search through the whole list each time you want to find something you can find it immediately.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to turn the int array into a hash where the int is the key and the value.  Then you can look it up directly with `if (exists($intHash{$iVal))`

Answer (score 0):

there's also the 'grep' method

if ( grep /$num/, @array ) { print "yerp!\n"; }

Comment: Or better: `if ( grep { $_ == $num } @array ) { print "yurp!\n"; }`